# Adding Multiple buttons in Toast or Snackbar

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

Is it possible to display multiple buttons/actions in a **toast** or **snackbar** using the .Net Maui Community Toolkit? If so, can you provide an example please? if not, is there another way to achieve this.
I have looked at all the documentation I can find but have not been able to find a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. On Android it uses the platform implementation as this concept is actually something that comes from Android. And on Android you cannot have more than 1 button on it. On other platforms we draw our own SnackBar/Toast, but to make sure it is consistent across platforms, we only allow 1 button to be on there.